# When "ali-" gets merged with the tabelvortoj - An example of irregularity in Esperanto

Tags: language-evolution

This is a common mistake (or proposal) I have seen in Esperanto; I have recently heard the word "alies" when listening to ĈRI, and I have also encountered it in Hasegawa Teru's (Verda Majo's) [*En Ĉinio Batalanta*](http://wikilivres.ca/wiki/En_%C4%88inio_Batalanta):

> **Aliel** ol en Japanio, ĉi tie mi ne bezonis konsideri la ideon kaj socian situacion de kunparolanto.

There is also a PMEG page about this issue:

["Ĉu ALI-vortoj povas esti tabelvortoj?"](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/tabelvortoj/ali-vortoj.html)

> Multfoje oni proponis aldoni al la tabelvortoj la antaŭparton *ALI-* kreante la novan serion *aliu*°, *alio*°, *alia*°, *alies*, *alie*°, *aliam*°, *alial*°, *aliel*, *aliom*°. Iuj eĉ praktikas tion uzante precipe la vortojn *aliel* kaj *alies*.

I would say the problem is well-treated in that PMEG article, but I'd appreciate an English-language summary of why this is considered incorrect.

It seems to be such a natural mistake, so natural that many people come to it spontaneously without having seen it before, and others try to defend it and use it purposely. For this reason I think it's an important issue to highlight and explain, because it seems like a possible hotspot of natural evolution and unintended development of irregularity in the casual use of the Esperanto language. Since Esperanto is a living language, I feel it's not in anyone's power anymore to stamp out natural growth. But because Esperanto is often touted as a completely regular language this seems to be a bit of a glaring contradiction to that claim. Of course "ali-" tabelvortoj are not official, but they seem to appear commonly in day to day writing and speech, intentionally or not.

So, why are these *ali-* tabelvortoj considered to be incorrect? And, if it doesn't convolute this question too much, has anyone else seen examples of irregularities like this in Esperanto, whether embedded within the 'official' Esperanto language or sliding by undetected in the flawed, natural, everyday speech of its speakers?

Comment: I would like to see a discussion sometime about the inevitability of ungrammatical casual speech and writing developing in our language, but I'm sure that is straying much too far from this question's scope. This SE is the first I've ever participated in so I would appreciate tips/opinions on shaving my questions down if they're too broad. I want this SE and all in-depth information and discussion about Esperanto to be successful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why it is considered incorrect is simply because, as PMEG states, *ali* already is a defined root. Thus *alio*, *alia*, *alie* etc. are already words, whose definition need not coincide with the proposed definitions of the correlative-equivalent. (In particular, *alie* would then mean ‘elsewhere’, *alia* would only be ‘another kind’ and not ‘other’ in a more general sense.)

The reason why PMEG (and also PIV) recommends not using the other correlative-suffixes to the root *ali* is because it would cause confusion. If someone uses *alies* and *aliel*, one may extrapolate that *alie* means ‘elsewhere’, which it does not. This would cause confusion.

The remainder of the PMEG article further points out some illogicalities of using *ali-* as a correlative root. For instance, that you could no longer say *alikaze*, because with correlatives, you cannot remove the suffix: We say *tiukaze*, not *tikaze*, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the answer of @Joffysloffy

If you combine *ali-* with a corelative root like *-io*, *-iam*, *-iel* you would end up with *aliio*, *aliiam*, *aliiel*, etc rather than with *aliom*, *aliam*, *aliel*.

Last not least, there are good alternatives like *alispeca*, *aliloke*, *alitempe*, *alifoje*, *alikvante*, *alia* ...

Comment: When they suggest the transformation of *ali* as a correlative, that *i* is the intermediate *i* from all correlatives, so you would actually get *alio*, *alia*, *alie*, *aliu*, *aliam*, etc. Or was that not your point?